# Apache Commons JCS 1.4-SNAPSHOT Maven Repository

Tags: apache, maven, jcs

Is there a maven repository for JCS 1.4-SNAPSHOT.  I've searched the Apache repositories, but can't seem to find it.  Also is JCS still under active development?  The mailing lists seem to be down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache.jcs) there you will find a 1.3 release but i have rechecked the [SNAPSHOT repository of the project](https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots) and couldn't find a up-to-date release. The current site is of the 19.feb 2012 ..so not that old. But if you don't get an answer on the mailing list Hm...

Comment: Literally the mailing list bounces at this point.  It isn't a lack of activity, I just can't subscribe.